# Error while showing button for specific user (Admin) odoo 8

Tags: xpath, odoo, odoo-8, qweb

I've inherited a form view and made some modifications using xpath. I need a button in the header of form view to show only to admin user. But when I'm putting the groups, its giving following error :

Error details:

[error_details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ObKCJ.png)

My code is:

```
<record id="wms_stock_view_move_form" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">wms.stock.view.move.form</field>
        <field name="model">stock.move</field>
        <field name="inherit_id" ref="stock.view_move_form" />
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <field name="location_id" position="attributes">
                <attribute name="domain">[('name','!=', 'Scrapped')]</attribute>
            </field>
            <field name="location_dest_id" position="attributes">
                <attribute name="domain">[('name','!=', 'Scrapped')]</attribute>
            </field>
            <xpath expr='//form[@string="Stock Moves"]' position='attributes'>
                <attribute name="create">false</attribute>
                <attribute name="edit">false</attribute>
                <attribute name="delete">false</attribute>
            </xpath>
            <xpath expr='//button[@name="action_cancel"]' position='attributes'>
                <attribute name="invisible">True</attribute>
            </xpath>
            <button name="action_done" states="draft,assigned,confirmed" string="Process Entirely" type="object" class="oe_highlight" position="replace" groups="base.group_no_one"/>
        </field>
</record>
```

Answer (score 0):

I eventually solved my own question, the solution is:

```
<xpath expr='//button[@name="action_done"]' position='replace'>
                <button name="action_done" states="draft,assigned,confirmed" string="Process Entirely" type="object" class="oe_highlight" position="replace" groups="base.group_no_one"/>
</xpath>
```

Comment: In your previous code, you added admin group. But here you added some custom group?

Comment: I won't replace the whole button, because other (extension) views changes could get lost with it.

Answer (score 0):

I have to guess which button you want to set new groups to, because your error relates to `action_done` but your own answer to `action_cancel`. So let me do this abstractly. You already have the answer in your question. Use XPath to "find" the button and use `position="attributes"`:

```xml
<xpath expr="//button[@name='button_name']" position="attributes">
    <attribute name="groups">module_name.group_id</attribute>
</xpath>
```

Comment: actually I had 2 buttons, action_cancel and action_done. it was my mistake that I put action_done in question and action_cancel in answer. I'm editing my answer now. Thanks for pointing out.